# How to check shell options?

Tags: bash

I want to check what options are enabled for my current shell.  For example, I want to know whether I was invoked with `-x` or `-e` or any number of other options.

I `source` a shell script with shebang line `#!/bin/bash -x` and later attempt to turn off 'x' with a `set +x` at the end of the script.  Now I want to check whether my `set +x` line succeeded.

#### Attempted solution

I've discovered `printenv` and `set` as ways to inspect some info about the current shell, but neither of them seem to contain a variable that stores `x` `e` or the like.

Comment: Is your *real* question really the last sentence in this post? Please read http://xyproblem.info/ and tell us more about that, if this is the actual problem. This will give you better answers.

Comment: @slhck, thank you for that link.  i've attempted to update with a better question.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the `$-` variable.

See the [documentation for the `set` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set) -- scroll down to the end and you'll see "The current set of options may be found in `$-`."

A quick demo

```
$ bash
$ echo $-
himBH
$ set -f; set +H
$ echo $-
fhimB
$ [[ $- == *i* ]] && echo This is an interactive shell
This is an interactive shell
```

Comment: What about other options set with `shopt`?

Comment: Found `$BASHOPTS` and `$SHELLOPTS`  via [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208244/22046)

Answer (score 1):

There's also `$BASHOPTS` and `$SHELLOPTS`.

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208244/22046)